# Command line: piping find results to rm

Tags: unix, command-line, find, rm

I'm trying to work out a command which deletes sql files older than 15 days.

The find part is working but not the rm.

```
rm -f | find -L /usr/www2/bar/htdocs/foo/rsync/httpdocs/db_backups -type f  \( -name '*.sql' \) -mtime +15
```

It kicks out a list of exactly the files I want deleted but is not deleting them.  The paths are correct.

```
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dIPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
/usr/www2/bar/htdocs/foo/rsync/httpdocs/db_backups/20120601.backup.sql
...
/usr/www2/bar/htdocs/foo/rsync/httpdocs/db_backups/20120610.backup.sql
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 352, accepted):

You are actually piping `rm`'s **output** to the input of `find`. What you want is to use the output of `find` as **arguments** to `rm`:

```
find -type f -name '*.sql' -mtime +15 | xargs rm
```

`xargs` is the command that "converts" its standard input into arguments of another program, or, as they more accurately put it on the `man` page,

> build and execute command lines from standard input

Note that if file names can contain whitespace characters, you should correct for that:

```
find -type f -name '*.sql' -mtime +15 -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

But actually, `find` has a shortcut for this: the `-delete` option:

```
find -type f -name '*.sql' -mtime +15 -delete
```

Please be aware of the following warnings in `man find`:

```
  Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated
  as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to
  delete everything below the starting points you specified.  When
  testing a find command line that you later intend  to  use  with
  -delete,  you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid
  later surprises.  Because -delete  implies  -depth,  you  cannot
  usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

<sub>P.S. Note that piping directly to `rm` isn't an option, because `rm` doesn't expect filenames on standard input. What you are currently doing is piping them backwards.</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  I read the man page and gave that flag a try.  I'm passing a full path but getting back "/usr/www2/bar/htdocs/foo/rsync/httpdocs/db_backups/: relative path potentially not safe".  Any idea why?

Comment: @jerrygarciuh take a look [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg16944.html).

Comment: thanks.  I am not sure I followed the post well but when I emulated their solution and put -delete at the end of the command it deleted all of the sql files regardless of mod time...  but it didn't have the warning so I guess that's progress...

Comment: @jerrygarciuh Ouch, I hope nothing valuable was lost... `man` says: `When testing a find command line that you later intend to use with -delete, you  should explicitly  specify  -depth  in  order to avoid later surprises.` I'm not sure how that would matter given the other options you used, though, but did you try that?

Comment: Nope I didn't but nothing was lost.  These files are rsync-ed from another server where they are also stored.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh um, so did you figure it out? was `'-depth'` the reason?

Comment: Hi Lev, I don't actually know because our sysadmin took the job and resolved it some other way.  So much for learning by doing!

Comment: @sarat The second and third commands handle it correctly. In the 2nd command, a \\0 character is used to separate the arguments instead of a space. In the 3rd one, find handles it internally.

Comment: ahhh finally!!! thank you so much this is great, I had no clue about xargs

Answer (score 35):

```
find /usr/www/bar/htdocs -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
```

Will select files in `/usr/www/bar/htdocs` older than 15 days and remove them.

Comment: I prefer your answer than the one accepted because of the "space in the name". It's better handled with the "-exec" command than pipe. Thanks.

Comment: How to pipe the files deleted to a log file? ` rm {} >> my.log` doesn't fly.

Answer (score 13):

Another simpler method is to use `locate` command. Then, pipe the result to `xargs`.

For example,

```
locate file | xargs rm
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I didn't want to use `find` nor `locate`, hence there are faster alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Use **xargs** to pass arguments, with the option **-rd '\n'** to ignore spaces in names:

> "${command}" | xargs -rd '\n' rm

Include **--force** if you want to also remove read only files.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you aren't in the directory containing the *.sql backup files:

```
find /usr/www2/bar/htdocs/foo/rsync/httpdocs/db_backups/*.sql -mtime +15 -exec rm -v {} \;
```

The -v option above is handy it will verbosely output which files are being deleted as they are removed.

I like to list the files that will be deleted first to be sure. E.g:

```
find /usr/www2/bar/htdocs/foo/rsync/httpdocs/db_backups/*.sql -mtime +15 -exec ls -lrth {} \;
```