# find and remove multiple file using linux command

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I have a directory named `classes` which contains a lot of sub-directories -

```
classes  
  |-security  
  |-registration  
  |-service  
 ....
```

Each of these directory contains a lot of `java` files and their compiled classes files. I want to remove all the class file.

Going to `classes` directory I can list out all the class file using find command -

```
$ find . -name *.class
```

Is there any command in linux to remove all the classes file under the `classes` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer uses the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find . -name "*.class" -exec rm {} \;
```

Be sure to quote the wildcard, to ensure that it is passed into `find` (rather than globbed by the shell, first).

For further discussion, see these questions:

- [Command line: piping find results to rm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191475/command-line-piping-find-results-to-rm)
- [Linux why can't I pipe find result to rm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307299/linux-why-cant-i-pipe-find-result-to-rm)

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` with pipe lining -

```
$ find . -name *.class | xargs rm *
```

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit? Although, you are not using xargs, but a pipe to rm, which isn't necessary and may slow things down when compared to  `-exec rm`.