# (AppleScript) Remove files from subfolders with shell script

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I have a script that moves files to Trash, but I work with tens of thousands of files so I need it to do fast. Current script gets Finder stuck and I need to relaunch Finder every time I use the script.

```
set source_folder to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder) & "4K Stogram"

do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of source_folder & " -type f -exec /bin/mv {} ~/.Trash \\;"

display notification "All images were processed." with title "New" sound name "Glass.aiff"
tell me to quit
```

Wouldn't the shell script's 'rm -f' command make it faster?
How the script should look like if yes?
I don't need those files in Trash anyway, I delete them right after the script finishes the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-delete` option to the `find` command.

Like this:

```
set source_folder to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder) & "4K Stogram"
do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & (quoted form of source_folder) & " -type f -delete"
```

Comment: Worked like magic! Last little question: is there a way to add pop-up alert when this script is running? Like in trash

Comment: put this before the first line `display alert "Do you want to delete every file in the '4K Stogram' folder?" buttons {"No", "Delete"} cancel button "No"`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you big time!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [pipe your find results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191475/command-line-piping-find-results-to-rm) to the rm command.  Understand that although rm should be faster, it is permanent.  Be sure that your code is correct before invoking it.

Comment: I get that, but could you maybe help with writing it? I actually understand nothing in it.